# Using "Prescience"

Tags: meaning, word-usage, sentence

Is it alright if I use the word "prescience" in this manner, since the term prescience means to know something in advance?

*From the looks of the dark clouds outside the window, I've got a **prescience** that a downpour will come any moment.*

Thanks!

Comment: "prescience" is to know something in advance without relying on evidence. The use of evidence makes it a prediction. Prescience is "magic" knowledge that you cannot learn from the facts around you.

Comment: It wouldn't have sounded so unusual [a century or two ago](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=had+a+prescience&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Chad%20a%20prescience%3B%2Cc0), but we don't use ***a** prescience* like that much today ([presentiment, premonition](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=a+prescience%2Ca+presentiment%2Ca+premonition&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ca%20prescience%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ca%20presentiment%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ca%20premonition%3B%2Cc0) are more likely)

Answer (score 1):

I think a better word would be *premonition*

> 1. a feeling of anticipation of or anxiety over a future event; presentiment: He had a vague premonition of danger.
> 2. a forewarning.

Prescience carries an different implication of pre-knowledge

Comment: I think premonition has the same problem as prescience. Both mean an advanced knowledge of something that cannot be known from the available evidence. The only difference is that premonition is not a certain as prescience suggests.

Comment: *Premonition* is definitely better since it's a countable noun (while *prescience* is not), but I agree that neither is a good fit for the "I reach a conclusion based on evidence" element of the original sentence.

Comment: Moreover, I think "prescience" is more of a quality one has than the actual foretelling|prognostication|premonition|prediction of a specific event.

Answer (score 1):

"prescience" is to know something in advance without relying on evidence.

The use of evidence makes it a prediction, so you could say:

*From the looks of the dark clouds outside the window, I predict that it will rain any minute now.*

Prescience is "magic" knowledge that you cannot learn from the facts around you.

Predictions are conclusions about future events based on the evidence that is available currently.

Answer (score 0):

The word you are after might be ***presentiment*** (already mentioned, but in the context of *premonitions*), defined [here](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/presentiment) as ‘a feeling or impression that something is about to happen, especially something evil; foreboding.’

*Presentiment* lacks the sense of *certainty* in prescience and premonition.

Another possibility is to call this sense an ***intuition***, with several definitions [here](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/intuition), including ‘immediate apprehension or cognition’, and ‘knowledge or conviction gained by intuition’.

The point there is that an *intuition* is of something specific, although solid *evidence* of its approach might be lacking, so again it is less certain than a premonition, which be more like convincingly *seeing* something in advance.